# Get all files in array order by name c#

Tags: c#, filelist

string mypath = txtPath.Text;

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(mypath);

foreach (FileInfo fi in d.EnumerateFiles("*.jpg").OrderBy(x => x.Name))
            txtStatus.Text = txtStatus.Text + fi.Name + Environment.NewLine;
```

the result of this I'm getting is this

```
banner-noche-estrellas-zacatecas2015.jpg  
banner-noche-estrellas-zacatecas2015_10.jpg  
banner-noche-estrellas-zacatecas2015_11.jpg  
banner-noche-estrellas-zacatecas2015_12.jpg  
banner-noche-estrellas-zacatecas2015_13.jpg  
banner-noche-estrellas-zacatecas2015_14.jpg  
banner-noche-estrellas-zacatecas2015_15.jpg  
banner-noche-estrellas-zacatecas2015_16.jpg  
banner-noche-estrellas-zacatecas2015_17.jpg  
banner-noche-estrellas-zacatecas2015_18.jpg  
banner-noche-estrellas-zacatecas2015_19.jpg  
banner-noche-estrellas-zacatecas2015_2.jpg  
banner-noche-estrellas-zacatecas2015_20.jpg  
banner-noche-estrellas-zacatecas2015_21.jpg
```

---

I should get this:

```
banner-noche-estrellas-zacatecas2015.jpg  
banner-noche-estrellas-zacatecas2015_2.jpg  
banner-noche-estrellas-zacatecas2015_3.jpg
```

and so on

Comment: This is called "Natural Sort" and it is a lot more complex than a simple sort as I have explained in my answer to your previous question. You could find something useful in [this question/answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting them in order. The problem is that they are strings, so you are getting them in string order.

The most straightforward solution is to rename your files so that they have the same number of digits, e.g. `banner-noche-estrellas-zacatecas2015_2.jpg` -> `banner-noche-estrellas-zacatecas2015_02.jpg`

If you do that, your method will work.

If you don't want to do that, then you need to parse that number as an int before invoking the sort. Use a regex to do that.

Comment: Actualy, a regex is probably overkill. This will get you an `int` to sort by: `var sortOrder = int.Parse("0" + fi.Name.Replace("banner-noche-estrellas-zacatecas2015", "").Replace("_", "").Replace(fi.Extension, "");`